# Comparar cadenas en C ejercicio

Tags: c

tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

Implementar una función que se le pase como entrada dos cadenas de caracteres. La función deberá devolver un 1 si las cadenas son iguales, sino devolverá un 0 (no puede hacer uso de funciones especificas de C).

Esto es lo que intenté:

```
#include<stdio.h>

 char cadenas (char cad1[100],char cad2[100] ) {


int i;


 for (i=0;i<100;i++){

    printf ("\nintroduzca el caracter %s de la cadena");
        scanf  ("%s", cad1[i]);

}


 for (i=0;i<100;i++) {

   printf ("\nintroduzca el caracter %s de la cadena");
    scanf ("%s",cad2[i]);

}


 if (cad1==cad2) {

   printf ("las cadenas %s son iguales");

      return 1;
```

Lo que pasa es que al compilarlo me salen varios warnings, no sé qué errores podría tener el código:

```
ejexamen.c: In function ‘cadenas’:
ejexamen.c:22:11: warning: format ‘%s’ expects a matching ‘char *’ argument [-Wformat=]
   printf ("\nintroduzca el caracter %s de la cadena");
           ^
ejexamen.c:23:12: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
    scanf  ("%s", cad1[i]);
            ^
ejexamen.c:30:12: warning: format ‘%s’ expects a matching ‘char *’ argument [-Wformat=]
    printf ("\nintroduzca el caracter %s de la cadena");
            ^
ejexamen.c:31:10: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   scanf ("%s",cad2[i]);
          ^
ejexamen.c:38:12: warning: format ‘%s’ expects a matching ‘char *’ argument [-Wformat=]
    printf ("las cadenas %s son iguales");
            ^
ejexamen.c:42:8: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘else’
        else { 
        ^
```

Gracias

Answer (score 3):

Centrandome tan solo en el código, sin mirar los mensajes:

```
printf ("\nintroduzca el caracter %s de la cadena");
```

Indicas que quieres mostrar una cadena (`%s'), pero **no la pasas como argumento de la función**. Deberia ser

```
printf( "\nintroduzca el caracter %d de la cadena", i );
```

para mostrar el índice (que creo que es lo que quieres).

```
scanf  ("%s", cad1[i]);
```

Ahí, pides una **cadena**, pero le pasas como argumento **un caracter**. Debría de ser:

```
scanf( "%c", &cad1[i] );
```

y te saldrá un comportamiento *curioso* al ejecutarlo, pero lo dejo para que lo descubras tú ;-)

Todo lo anterior te vuelve a pasar otra vez, en el siguiente trozo de código.

Por último, haces

```
if (cad1==cad2)
```

Eso te va a dar *false* **siempre**. Lo que estas haciendo es comparar *punteros* a cadenas, que no es lo que tu pretendes.

Para comparar **el contenido** de las cadenas, lo mas fácil que se me ocurre es

```
while( ( *cad1 && *cad2 ) && ( *cad1 == *cad2 ) ) {
  ++cad1;
  ++cad2;
}

if( *cad1 == *cad2 ) {
  // Son iguales.
  ...
} else {
  // Son distintas.
  ...
}
```

Y por último, yo cambiaria la definición de la función por algo así:

```
int cadenas( char *cad1, char *cad2 ) {
```

principalemente, por claridad. No afecta realmente.

Ah, se me olvidaba. Te faltan 2 `}` al final de tu código. Supongo que no lo has copiado/pegado bien.